# Puppeteer's query selector returns null, although it exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Ran into a problem that `querySelector()` returns `null` for an element that exists on the page.
I looked up stackover flow for some answers, I tried:

```
waitForSelector() & page.setUserAgent(UserAgent)
```

When I manually run the script `document.querySelector('span.s-item__price')` in the chrome console, it returned what I was expecting, but not when I tried with puppeteer.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function openBrowser(url, callback) {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    defaultViewport: {
        width: 1920,
        height: 1080
    }
});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto(`${url}`);
await callback(page);
await browser.close();
}


openBrowser('https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2380057.m570.l1313&_nkw=men+watch&_sacat=0', async (page) => {

const products = await page.evaluate(() => {

    let resultArray = [];
    const productsArray = [...document.querySelectorAll('li.s-item.s-item__pl-on-bottom')];

    for (let i = 1; i < productsArray.length; i++) {
        resultArray.push({
            id: i,
            title: productsArray[i].querySelector('h3.s-item__title').textContent,
            img: productsArray[i].querySelector('img.s-item__image-img').src,
            price: productsArray[i].querySelector('span.s-item__price').textContent,
            // seller: productsArray[i].querySelector('.s-item__seller-info-text').textContent THIS ONE FAILS, TOP ONES WORK FINE.
        });
    }

    return resultArray;

});

console.log(products);

});
```

Comment: I'm not clear what the expected output is. Is the problem with the seller info text or the price? Arrays run from 0, so I assume you intended to skip the first element by starting at 1.

Comment: @ggorlen Yes, skip was needed for the first element. The output should be a list of simple scrape data from the ebay platform, but the last property of the object - seller, it fails with an error msg: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'textContent'), but when run manually in the console of the browser -it is fine.

I assume that this .s-item__seller-info-text is dynamically rendered on the page, but not sure how to get it.

Comment: Gotcha--thanks. I see why you're skipping the first element, it appears to be a placeholder. After a bunch of runs, I see the seller sometimes, but it doesn't appear to be consistently rendered in this view.